# Simple upload gmail api Email

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Can someone teach me how to make a simple upload of file and send it in codeigniter using and Gmail api php thanks in advance so far i have this

```
    $user = 'me';
    $strRawMessage = "To: $sendTo \r\n";

    $strRawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= " $message \r\n";

    $strRawMessage .= " Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='test.jpg'\r\n";

    // The message needs to be encoded in Base64URL

    $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $msg->setRaw($mime);

    // $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
```

Comment: What is not working for you? Are you getting any error?

Comment: it is sending in the email but the file that I've tried to cannot be seen and when I have open the message I get something like this without the test upload file:

Content-Type: image/jpeg MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename'test.jpg'

Comment: because the sample in the documentation is in java and I need a php